# java.lang.IllegalStateException - Couldn't find column

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have this code which corrects the MLE value to MALE. I first make a distinct value of Gender, then next is I will correct the wrong spelling.

```
genderTypeDim = (
    qualificationConsolidatedData.select("GenderType"))
    .distinct()
    .dropna("all")
)

genderTypeDim.show()

genderTypeDim = genderTypeDim .withColumn(
    "GenderType",
    F.when(F.col("GenderType") == "MLE", "MALE").otherwise(
        F.col("GenderType")
    ),
).distinct()

genderTypeDim.show()

genderTypeDim = genderTypeDim .withColumn(
    "GenderTypeSortOrder",
    F.when(F.col("GenderType") == "Male", 1)
    .when(F.col("GenderType") == "Female", 2)
    .otherwise(3),
)

genderTypeDim.show()
```

However, when I run this code, it gives me an error like this. (It prints the two show DF, then the error):

```
+---------------+
|     ChangeType|
+---------------+
|        Bespoke|
|Multi-qualified|
|    Non-bespoke|
+---------------+

+---------------+
|     ChangeType|
+---------------+
|    Non-bespoke|
|Multi-qualified|
+---------------+

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn&#39;t find GenderType#232317 in [CASE WHEN (GenderType#232317 = MLE) THEN MALE ELSE GenderType#232317 END#244149]
```

If I removed the distinct in the first code, the error will be gone. Can you explain why?

```
genderTypeDim = (
    qualificationConsolidatedData.select("GenderType"))
    .dropna("all")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I have used the same code:

[image]

- However when I have updated the code as below, I got the result as required. I have removed `distinct` from the statement where we are changing `MLE` to `MALE` and then assigning it to a new dataframe:

```
genderTypeDim = df.select("GenderType").distinct().dropna("all")
genderTypeDim.show()

genderTypeDim = genderTypeDim.withColumn("GenderType2",when(col("GenderType") == "MLE", "MALE").otherwise(col("GenderType")),).distinct()  #Create new column to avoid conflict
genderTypeDim.withColumn("new_col",when(genderTypeDim.GenderType2 == "MALE", 1).when(genderTypeDim.GenderType2 == "FEMALE", 2).otherwise(3)).show()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why this error occur? I also remove the distinct in the code. But I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: I have edited the solution. The reason might be that the original `GenderType#<some_id>` is being looked at while using when case but since we have used `withColumn` to make changes the column might have become `GenderType#<new_id>` and thus the conflict.